# The purpose of the Thieves Guild

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there any purpose to the Thieves Guild other than to introduce the Scoundrel? Do they show up again in a random dungeon/cave?

Comment: I would note that upon dying, Nigel Cutthroat says "This isn't over, the rest of the Thieves Guild will find you...".  This leads me to believe as others have stated on the web that Thieves Guild may play a role in the expansion.  The Scoundrel is certainly a beloved character, after all.

Answer (score 2):

Outside of introducing the Scoundrel and being mentioned in his personal story, they don't appear again. As they're based out of Kingsport, it's possible that if an expansion ever visits there, they may play a part - but currently, there's only those scant few mentions to go by.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't paid much attention to context but being at my 4th playthrough (normal twice and nightmare once, then hell now), I haven't seen the Thieves Guild again.

Answer (score 1):

The theives guild is an fictional archetype that symbolises criminal organisations. They are found in many works of fiction (not just games) eg. Assassin's Creed (game), The Elder Scrolls series (game), Ice Age (novel) and The Black Magician (novel).

They aren't mentioned again in Diablo 3, except in dialogue with the Scoundrel.

No doubt this reference in Diablo 3 will be followed up in a sequel in the same way Ashera of the Iron Wolves was introducted in Diablo 2. And in the same way, Wirt was a child in Diablo 1, dead in Diablo 2 and his looted items are still available in Diablo 3.